# Depth-cyclic list

Tags: scheme, cyclic

```
(define depth-count
  (lambda (l)
    (let ((visited '())
          (counter 0))
      (let iter ((l l))
         (cond ((pair? l) 
                (if (memq l visited)
                    (set! counter (+ 1 counter))
                    (begin
                       (set! visited (cons l visited))
                       (iter (car l))
                       (iter (cdr l)))))
               (else '()))) counter)))
```

Imho, that else branch is unnecessary or just wrong, however that code seems to work, but I am not sure..
When I have .. let's say

```
(define l0 '(a b c))
(set-car! l0 l0)
(set-car! (cdr l0) l0)
(depth-count l0)
```

It should return 2, right? Is is correct then?

Comment: Please split this into two separate questions. Otherwise if one person answers your first question and someone else answers the second, whose answer will you accept?

Comment: So your procedure counts how many self references there are? What does that have to do with depth?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the expression `(else '())` is superfluous. It means that your *cond* expression will sometimes evaluate to the empty list. Hence, your inner *let* will sometimes evaluate to the empty list.

It is superfluous because you are not using the result of the inner *let* for anything. The result is discarded by the outer *let*, which returns the value of its final sub-expression: `counter`.

Yes, 2 is a reasonable (predictable) result for the input you've suggested.

As for its correctness, you really need to state more clearly what you are trying to achieve. The 'depth' of a 'cyclic list' is not a well-defined concept.